# calendar android

Tags: java, android

how can i catch calendar events in android? (when i have a calendar event right now i will do  something?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documentation doesn't directly refer to the ability of catching an event. I'm assuming you want to "catch" the notifications that pop-up? You can see all the Calendar Provider information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

What I would suggest trying, is hook up your phone to your computer with Eclipse and Logcat running. Have a calendar event fire, and see what kind of Intent (if any) was thrown. Then you can just add that type of Intent handler to your application.

**UPDATE**

I've done just what I described above. It looks like a com.android.providers.calendar.action.SCHEDULE_EVENT_AWARE intent is being broadcasted. The problem is it also specifies the component to answer this request com.android.providers.calendar/.EventAwareService

Comment: hi, thanks for help, i already look at the Calndar documentation in android developer however i still dont understand how can i implement it? and yes, i want to catch the notification(the information about the event that i need to perform right now) can you post an example code to help me? thanks in advance

Comment: You can't catch a notification (as far as I know). That notification was posted by a Service (EventAwareService). This service is launched by the Intent I posted above. I'll play around but I don't think you CAN tap into the Calendar Schedule Event. I'll let you know if I find out a way

Comment: so can you post the code how to catch the event?(if you will know how to do it) thanks alot